# selectBooleanCheckbox is not set after remoteCommand

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a remmoteCommand that updates a List, after the items are loaded a repeat render selectBooleanCheckbox. However, the values are not correctly set at the checkbox, all of them are unchecked beside there are some items with selected property (which is Boolean) set to true.

If I just set an Item in the backing bean after the list is loaded it works only for that Item. What could be the problem?

index.xhtml

```
 <h:form>
        <h:panelGroup id="itemsHolder">
            <h:panelGrid rendered="#{backingBean.items != null}">
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{backingBean.item.selected}" disabled="#{backingBean.rendered}" /> #{backingBean.item.name}
                <ui:repeat value="#{backingBean.items.toArray()}" var="option" >
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{option.selected}" disabled="#{backingBean.rendered}" />
                    #{option.name}
                    <br />
                </ui:repeat>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <p:remoteCommand rendered="#{backingBean.rendered}"
                         name="initItems"
                         actionListener="#{backingBean.initItems()}"
                         process="@this"
                         update="itemsHolder"/>

    </h:form>

    <ui:fragment rendered="#{backingBean.rendered}">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    initItems();
                }, 3000);

            });
        </script>
    </ui:fragment>
```

BackingBean.java

```
@Component
@ManagedBean
@Scope("view")
public class BackingBean {

private boolean rendered = true;

private Set<Item> items;

private Item item;

public void initItems() {
    items = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    items.add(new Item("item 1", true, "1"));
    items.add(new Item("item 2", false, "2"));
    items.add(new Item("item 3", true, "3"));

    item = new Item("lonely item", true, "4");
   }

//Getters and setters
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I created a copy of the real code in a SandBox, I am still not able to reproduce, I think I will have to add more dependencies from real code.

Comment: Where is the remote command? Better yet, where is your [mcve]?

Comment: I added the piece of code to another project, to create the minimal, verifiable example, but I could not reproduce it. The thing is that the project has so many dependencies and frameworks that it would take a while. Until now the problem is only happening in my local environment. I will come back when I have finished the task, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated your case and it is working just fine with following simple managed bean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@ViewScoped
public class YourBean implements Serializable {
    List<YourItem> items=new ArrayList<>();
    YourItem anItem=new YourItem();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Bean is created");
        //initialize items
        anItem.setSelected(false);
        //add 5 items to list
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            YourItem item=new YourItem();
            item.setSelected(false);
            items.add(item);
        }
    }

    public void onUpdateItems(){
        System.out.println("Items will be updated...");
        anItem.setSelected(true);
        //modify 1st and 3rd item
        items.get(0).setSelected(true);
        items.get(2).setSelected(true);
        //remove 4th item
        items.remove(3);
    }

    public List<YourItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<YourItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public YourItem getAnItem() {
        return anItem;
    }

    public void setAnItem(YourItem anItem) {
        this.anItem = anItem;
    }
}
```

`p:command` should be implemented on following way

```
          <h:form id="form">
            <h:panelGroup id="itemHolder">
                <h:panelGrid rendered="#{bean.items != null}">
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.anItem.selected}" />
                    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{item.selected}" />
                        #{item.selected}
                        <br />
                    </ui:repeat>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <p:remoteCommand name="startUpdate" 
                             actionListener="#{bean.onUpdateItems()}" 
                             update=":form:itemHolder"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Update items" onclick="startUpdate();"/>
        </h:form>
```

Compare your code with this example. Very probably there is problem in your managed bean method for updating `items` List or with the way how you are updating `h:panelGroup`.

Comment: Hi, Dusan, I tried to replicate it in another project an actually works as you suspected. I think I should keep adding dependencies of the main project until I am able to reproduce it.